# Google Cloud Platform - I need a webhook to get JSON data. How to approach it?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform

I am fairly new to the google-cloud-platform world and I am struggling with my 1st steps there.
So, what I want to know is how to make a webhook app, that will run 24/7 and "catch" data sent from another 3rd party service (later I will try to do something with this data - manipulate it and push into a DB, but that's anohter question to ask).
I have set up an instance on GCP which Linux based, but , what's next?
I am familiar with PHP, but I want to do it this time in Phyton (learning it nowdays).
Which service in GCP should I use and how I set up the server to catch every data the 3rd party service is sending?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect fit for Google App Engine. As long as the 3rd-party service makes HTTP requests, App Engine is a great fit. You can write your application in Python, PHP, Java, or just about anything else, then GAE takes care of the rest. No need to manage Linux, instances, firewall rules, or anything else.

If your load is minimal, you may even fit into the free tier and pay nothing to run your app.

Check out the GAE Python docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/.

Comment: Thanks Eric - took me several runs on the documentation, but managed to get my 1st Json on the GAE :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your Web Hook continuously, then you can run it as a Cron job. Here is a guide on how to run Python scripts as cron jobs on Google App Engine: [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron)

Comment: Thanks Nadir - I think that the GAE runs all the time and I don't need CRONE for that...